# jQuery test 2 months

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a way to check if the first select menu's date is before the second.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
<select id="outbound_month_and_year">
<option selected="" value="-1">Departing</option>
<option selected="" value="NOV2013">November 2013</option>
<option value="DEC2013">December 2013</option>
<option value="JAN2014">January 2014</option>
<option value="FEB2014">February 2014</option>
<option value="MAR2014">March 2014</option>
<option value="APR2014">April 2014</option>
<option value="MAY2014">May 2014</option>
<option value="JUN2014">June 2014</option>
<option value="JUL2014">July 2014</option>
<option value="AUG2014">August 2014</option>
<option value="SEP2014">September 2014</option>
<option value="OCT2014">October 2014</option>
</select>

<select id="return_month_and_year">
<option selected="" value="-1">just one way</option>
<option value="NOV2013">November 2013</option>
<option value="DEC2013">December 2013</option>
<option value="JAN2014">January 2014</option>
<option value="FEB2014">February 2014</option>
<option value="MAR2014">March 2014</option>
<option value="APR2014">April 2014</option>
<option value="MAY2014">May 2014</option>
<option value="JUN2014">June 2014</option>
<option value="JUL2014">July 2014</option>
<option value="AUG2014">August 2014</option>
<option value="SEP2014">September 2014</option>
<option value="OCT2014">October 2014</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You need to change the values to strings which can easily be converted to `Date` type, eg. `01 Jun 2014`, convert them and compare.

Comment: I do not have access to such things

Comment: I thought you meant the markup

Comment: Ah, I get what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you say you cannot change the HTML you need to use string manipulation to get the date into a format it can be parsed. It's ugly code, but it works:

```
var $out = $('#outbound_month_and_year'),
    $in = $('#return_month_and_year');

$out.add($in).on('change', function() {
    var outDate = getDate($out.val()),
        inDate = getDate($in.val());

    if (outDate && inDate) {
        if (outDate < inDate) {
            $('#result').text('Outbound is before');
        }
        else if (outDate > inDate) {
            $('#result').text('Outbound is after');
        }
        else {
            $('#result').text('Outbound is the same');
        }
    }
});

function getDate(val) {
    if (val == -1)
        return false;

    var day = '01';
    var month = val.substr(0, 3);
    var year = val.substr(-4);
    return new Date(day + ' ' + month + ' ' + year);
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/gQ5U5/)

Be aware that this solution is very brittle in that it can be easily broken by the format of the `select` values being changed. If that happens you need to amend the `getDate()` function accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
$('select').on ('change', function () {
var date1 = new  Date($('#outbound_month_and_year').val());
    var date2 = new  Date($('#return_month_and_year').val());
    if (date1.getTime() < date2.getTime() ) {
    alert("date1 is less than date2");
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b3rU6/) this works in chrome but I think it might have cross browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('select').on ('change', function () {
if($('#outbound_month_and_year').val()!=-1 && $('#return_month_and_year').val()!=-1){
    var date1 = new  Date($('#outbound_month_and_year').val());
    var date2 = new  Date($('#return_month_and_year').val());
    if (date1.getTime() < date2.getTime() ) {
     // show message
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Returns an invalid date